# Excel macro formatting results different between workstations

Tags: excel

I am using a Macro to build a workbook, but the resultant file outputs a number as -0,26 on one workstation and the other workstation outputs the number as -,2600. When this file is carried over to other workstations the number format persists regardless of workstation. It carries the format originally created during file production on that workstation. The workstations render different results in the end.

These numbers are all formatted as General and the region settings has decimal character as , and number of decimal places as default of 2.

Zero's show as 0 on one and ,0000 or -,0000 on the other.

Any thoughts / ideas?

Comment: Do both machines have Excel set to the same Language/Region?

Comment: I'm just making sure. They are both VMs. I'll log into both, compare and revert.

Comment: This can sometimes happen if one of the `Cell Styles` get corrupted.  Right click on the various cell styles "number format" and select modify. *I don't know if anyone has figured out **why** this occurs*